# Centering web resource text

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

Long story short, I need to display some coloured text with a coloured background on a form.

The text is no longer than 1 line long and so I set the formatting of the web resource to 2 rows in size but unfortunately the text appears quite low on the web resource which means the text requires scrolling in order to be viewed...

Does anyone know of a way to have the text displayed **exactly** where the web resource is displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is probably with the margins of the IFRAME. See if the function below changes anything.

```js
function FormatIFRAME(IFRAMEID) {
    var iFrame, frameDoc;

    iFrame = document.getElementById(IFRAMEID);
    frameDoc = iFrame.contentWindow.document;
    frameDoc.body.topMargin = '0';
    frameDoc.body.leftMargin = '0';
    frameDoc.body.rightMargin = '0';
    frameDoc.body.bottomMargin = '0';
    frameDoc.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(246,248,250)";
    iFrame.style.border = "0";
}
```